# Azure Automation DSC Node not pulling the newest module

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

This what I did:

1. Upload a custom DSC module to Azure Automation account. (1.0.0)
2. Node uses module.
3. Change the module version in the psd1 of the module. Upload the new version. (1.0.1)
4. Node downloads newer version and uses it.
5. Change the module version in the psd1 again. (1.0.2)
6. Node is still reporting errors from module version 1.0.1

I have tried changing the major and minor version numbers in both the psd1 and the mof schema. I also tried deleting and redeploying the entire node! It is stuck on 1.0.1. Is there a cache in the Azure Automation pull server that could cause this?

Module version. Note the time it was uploaded:
[image]

Error reported from node. Notice the time reported and module version:
[image]

Comment: in your dsc config have u verified that you are not targeting the older version of the module? `Import-DscResource -ModuleName yourmodule -version 1.0.0`...

Comment: I did not specify a version in the configuration, but I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you re-compiled your configuration after the new module is imported? The node configuration (mof) is tied to a specific module version. So if you haven't re-compile the node configuration, the node configuration still refers to your previous module version therefore the node will pull the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your node's LCM has this setting "AllowModuleOverwrite" set to true :

```
AllowModuleOverwrite = $True
```